# Initialize ImageView in companion Object Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-companion

I am trying to initialize an ImageView in companion object as I want the methods to be static but I have an error is there an alternative approach below is my code

```
companion object {
    lateinit var bufferingAnimation : LoadingAnimation
    var bufferingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading)
    fun startBufferingAnimation() {
        bufferingAnimation = LoadingAnimation(bufferingIndicator)
        bufferingAnimation.startAnimation()
    }

    fun stopBufferingAnimation() {
        bufferingAnimation.clearAnimation()
    }

}
```

I am not able to initialize bufferingIndicator is there any alternate approach?

Answer (score 2):

Making a static view is not recommended because it can cause memory leaks but if still you need static view, you can try this:-

```
companion object {
        lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    }

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        imageView  =findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and I have one more question so if we define onCreate in companion object all other View's should be defined static?

Comment: @vinaykumar we can not defined  onCreate under companion and also companion under onCreate. It should be on class level access.

Comment: Yes I was confused with the brackets I got it Thank you for the help

Comment: If you find it helpful, please accept the answer so that other may find it useful :)

Comment: Yes yes I tried to upvote but I don’t have enough reputation , Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `initialise image view` in runtime :-

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view_example)
        val constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout) as ConstraintLayout
        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo)
        constraintLayout.addView(imageView)
    }
```

If you having `image view` in xml :-

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // get reference to ImageView
        val imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_click_me) as ImageView
    }
```

Comment: Ths for this val imageView = ImageView(this)
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo)